# setState doesn't set state properly when used in array map function (we aren't using hooks its old project)

Tags: reactjs

I have been trying to set a state of multiple variables based on the response array that I am getting from an api. Based on each element in response array I need to set up state of different variables in state object. I tried many answers on Stackoverflow but it doesn't seem to work for me. Any help will be appreciated...

```js
response.val.map(error => {
        this.setState({
          isHouseNumberValid: error.field.includes('houseNr') ? false : true,
          isZipcodevalid: error.field.includes('postalCode') ? false : true,
          isCityValid: error.field.includes('locationName') ? false : true,
          isStreetNameValid: error.field.includes('streetName') ? false : true
        });
        
      });
```

I uderstand that using setstate in map is not advisable if response is from an api. Hence it only works for the last element in the array. But I tried many other options it works with static array but doesn't work with api response.

Comment: I think it would be useful to see more code in your question. Like how are you handling the response from that API. Usually, you set your state variables to that response first, and then, you map through the state, and based on that, you can handle your logic

Comment: First, you can cut your code to `isHouseNumberValid: !error.field.includes('houseNr')` etc, no need for the extra ternary check since `includes` returns a boolean. Second, it's not a good use case for map. Map is used to transform values(you're not doing that here). Third think of a loop, when you assign values to the same variable, at the end the variable will only hold the last value. Please show the structure of the error and I can help further. If it's just a single array, then just assign based on indexes, no need to map.

Comment: I am not getting any error but like you said the way I was looping it is incorrect. Hence was only getting the last element. Also improved my code like you have suggested! Thank you :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are overriding the previous state each time you iterate over an item. You should only use `setState` once using the precalculated values.

```
this.setState({
  isHouseNumberValid: !response.val.find(error => error.field.includes('houseNr')),
  isZipcodevalid    : !response.val.find(error => error.field.includes('postalCode')),
  isCityValid       : !response.val.find(error => error.field.includes('locationName')),
  isStreetNameValid : !response.val.find(error => error.field.includes('streetName')),
});

// or

const errorFields = response.val.flatMap(error => error.fields);

this.setState({
  isHouseNumberValid: !errorFields.includes('houseNr'),
  isZipcodevalid    : !errorFields.includes('postalCode'),
  isCityValid       : !errorFields.includes('locationName'),
  isStreetNameValid : !errorFields.includes('streetName'),
});
```